# RecyclerView not showing in ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-constraintlayout

I'm trying to show a RecyclerView ("mapRecyclerView") below another ConstraintLayout ("clientData) inside a ConstraintLayout but it presents a strange behavior: RecyclerView ("mapRecyclerView") has a Top Constraint to the bottom of another ConstraintLayout ("clientData"), if this ConstraintLayout has width as specific dp the recyclerview shows fine but if the ConstraintLayout has a width of "match_constraint" the RecyclerView is not visible anymore and the "afterMeasured" event of the RecyclerView is never called, here is the XML of the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                                                   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                                                   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                                   android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                                   android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:elevation="4dp" app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            android:fontFamily="@font/gotham_rounded_book"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" android:theme="@style/custom_toolbar"/>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            android:id="@+id/clientData" android:background="@color/white"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent">

        <TextView
                android:text="1"
                android:layout_width="35dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:id="@+id/activeServiceNumber"
                android:background="@drawable/button_yellow_round_border" android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/name" android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                android:fontFamily="@font/gotham_rounded_medium"
                android:paddingTop="6dp" android:textColor="@color/white" android:layout_marginTop="8dp"/>
        <TextView
                android:text="TextView"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/name"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/activeServiceNumber" android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/gotham_rounded_medium" android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryText"
                android:textSize="16sp" android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp" app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/client"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/directionsBtn"/>
        <TextView
                android:text="TextView"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/client"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/activeServiceNumber" android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/gotham_rounded_light" android:textSize="15sp" android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/address"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/directionsBtn"/>
        <TextView
                android:text="TextView"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/address"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/activeServiceNumber" android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/gotham_rounded_light" android:textSize="13sp" android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/phone"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/directionsBtn"/>
        <TextView
                android:text="TextView"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/phone"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/activeServiceNumber" android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:textSize="13sp" android:fontFamily="@font/gotham_rounded_light" android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/directionsBtn"/>
        <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:id="@+id/directionsBtn"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                android:text="Mostrar \nRuta"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_go_to_route" android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:padding="10dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
              android:id="@+id/ongoingServiceMap"
              android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="0dp"
              android:clickable="true"
              app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
              app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
              tools:context="com.cargamos.cargamosdriver.views.service.OngoingServiceActivity"
              app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
              app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" android:focusable="true"
              app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/clientData"/>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/ongoingServiceMap"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:id="@+id/mapRecyclerView"
            android:background="@color/white"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/confirmArrivalSlider"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/clientData"/>

    <com.ncorti.slidetoact.SlideToActView
            android:id="@+id/confirmArrivalSlider"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:text="Confirmar llegada"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:slider_height="60dp"
            app:area_margin="4dp"
            app:outer_color="@color/colorPrimary" app:text_style="bold" app:text_size="18dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="32dp" android:layout_marginBottom="24dp" android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: According to google docs: "MATCH_PARENT is not recommended for widgets contained in a ConstraintLayout". You can just set width to 0dp and set the start and end constraints to parent.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what items you have in your `RecyclerView`, you probably want to set the width of the `RecyclerView` to `match_parent`.
By the way, I can't reproduce the problem you describe in the preview